# How to extract from text with in a range of time

Tags: python, regex

I have  a text below, How to extract the text between the time range. Code is available to extract all the values

```
s = '''00:00:14,099 --> 00:00:19,100
a classic math problem a

00:00:17,039 --> 00:00:28,470
will come from an unexpected place

00:00:18,039 --> 00:00:19,470

00:00:20,039 --> 00:00:21,470

00:00:22,100 --> 00:00:30,119
binary numbers first I'm going to give

00:00:30,119 --> 00:00:35,430
puzzle and then you can try to solve it

00:00:32,489 --> 00:00:37,170
like I said you have a thousand bottles'''
```

Can i extract the test from `00:00:17,039 --> 00:00:28,470` and `00:00:30,119`

code to write back all the values

```
import re
lines = s.split('\n')
dict = {}

for line in lines:
    is_key_match_obj = re.search('([\d\:\,]{12})(\s-->\s)([\d\:\,]{12})', line)
    if is_key_match_obj:
        #current_key = is_key_match_obj.group()
        print (current_key)
        continue

    if current_key:
        if current_key in dict:
            if not line:
                dict[current_key] += '\n'
            else:
                dict[current_key] += line
        else:
              dict[current_key] = line

print(dict.values())
```

Expected Out from `00:00:17,039 --> 00:00:28,470` to `00:00:30,119 --> 00:00:35,430`

```
dict_values(['will come from an unexpected place ', '', '', 'binary numbers first I'm going to give', ' puzzle and then you can try to solve it'])
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/cHIDAl/1 ?

Comment: I'd rather use some library that parses these SRT files. There are many libraries available out there.

Comment: @Rakesh pasted the expected out

Comment: Is the time range fixed or dynamic? Where do it come from? In your expected output, you have `puzzle and then...` but this text is **after** `00:00:30,119 --> 00:00:35,430`. Is it a typo?

Comment: time range is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to iterate line by line. Try the below code. It will give you a dictionary as you wanted.

```
import re
dict = dict(re.findall('(\d{2}:\d{2}.*)\n(.*)', s))
print(dict.values())
```

Output

```
dict_values(['a classic math problem a', 'will come from an unexpected place', '', '', "binary numbers first I'm going to give", 'puzzle and then you can try to solve it', 'like I said you have a thousand bottles'])
```

Comment: They don't want to get all the text, only between `00:00:17,039 --> 00:00:28,470` and `00:00:30,119`

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
line = re.sub(r'\d{2}[:,\d]+[ \n](-->)*', "", s)
print(line)
```

will print:

> " a classic math problem a\n\n will come from an unexpected place\n\n
>   \n \n binary numbers first I'm going to give\n\n puzzle and then you
>   can try to solve it\n\n like I said you have a thousand bottles"

Explanation

`'\d{2}[:,\d]`   capture two digits numbers followed by `:` or `,` or a number - this captures both start and end timelines

`[ \n]` : captures an empty space after the first timeline and line break after the end timeline

`(-->)*` : captures the occurrence of 0 or more -->

As some else suggested in the comment, you might want to look at parser that do this for you by building a parse tree. They are more full-proof. Google search leads me to this [srt python library](https://pypi.org/project/srt/)

Comment: can you explain the regex

Comment: added explanation

Comment: `[:,\d{3}]+` is a character class that matches 1 or more `:`, `,`, `\d`, `{` or `}`. `[ ^\n]` matches a space, a caret or a linefeed. Have a look at https://www.regular-expressions.info/ for an intro to regex.